# Running into problems with creating a file on Heroku (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

So I have a user model and upon a user's registration I need to generate a file with some specific user information in it. Heroku is not allowing me to do that. Is there any other option besides generating the file and writing it to an S3 bucket and referencing it from there.

Comment: what kind of user information? is this not something that you could just store in the database? more information on what type of information and how you want to use it in your app would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Heroku's file system is read-only. The only exception is the tmp dir, but that's, well, temporary.
S3 is a common solution. Another possibility is saving that "file" to the database (use a "text" column in your migration). You could also use some document store, such as CouchDB or MongoDB and store your "file" there. There are several Heroku add-ons for Couch and Mongo that even offer a free tier.

Comment: The actual file that needs to be generated is an xml file . It's fairly short but it does have some user variables. For example, the user registers with a phone number, and that number needs to be in the xml feed. Again, the feed needs to be generated upon user registration and must be accessed from a resource (/user/file.xml).

Comment: After reading some more about MongoDB it seems like it would be an elegant solution when using GridFS. Do you see any dis/advantages of doing so as opposed to S3? Will the mix of data stores cause any potential issues?

Comment: The main advantage of Mongo vs S3 is that S3 is rather slow. It's a good solution for large files, but if you need to load a file as part of serving a client request, then S3 response time is unsatisfactory imho.

Answer (score 1):

On the Cedar stack, the filesystem is ephemeral, which means that the filesystem only exists for the duration of the dyno (which is an unknown and unpredictable amount of time).

On the older stacks, only /tmp is writable, and again is ephemeral.

Therefore, to produce a file and export it you need to think about how you need to deliver the file.

If it's for a download later on, can you produce the file from the database at any time (thus saving the need for a file to be written out at all).

If it's for download now, stream it back to the end user.

It it's for export to S3, do that.