# Serve programmatically generated HTML file from NodeJS on Heroku

Tags: html, node.js, heroku

I have a ruby script which is deployed on Heroku, which generates certain HTML files under my apps folder under `/html`.

I am trying to serve up these files from a NodeJS app, which is present under the same app.
My `index.js` looks like this :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/html'));

// views is directory for all template files
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
var html = fs.readFileSync(__dirname+'/html/mytest.html', 'utf8')
response.send(html);
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

Now, even when I am reading the file on every request. I am getting the dummy copy of html file which I have committed with my github repo.

Is there a way if I can access this freshly overwritten copy of the html?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku file system is mostly read-only with a few exceptions.

Please check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9101857/7006062) and for real consider using S3 which seems to be a pretty straightforward solution.