# Python with open doesn't create new file after deployed at Heroku

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

I'm working on a python project in which I need to create a new JSON file.It's working locally but when I deploy my app to Heroku the file creation doesn't work.

Here's what I have tried:

From **settings.py**

```
APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))   # refers to application_top
APP_FINALIZED = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'finalized')
```

From **app.py**

```
HOME = os.path.join(APP_FINALIZED)
print(HOME)
with open(HOME + '/description_' + str(fid) + '.json', 'w', encoding="utf-8")\
        as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False))
```

> **Updated:**  can we write this file directly to the S3 bucket, anyway?

it's working fine locally, but when I deploy it on Heroku the file doesn't create, even it doesn't show any error.

Comment: Heroku's file system is (as far as I can remember read-only). Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/9101857/3126563

Comment: can we write it directly to s3 bucket?

Comment: Yes sir, you can. It's a great way to storage content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll add this as answer as well in case someone elese needs help.
**Heroku's file system is** (as far as I can remember) **read-only**. 
Please check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9101857/3126563).